# ios, Is there a change in push notification authorization callback

Tags: ios, authorization, push

In ios, if I authorize or reject Location Services when prompted, there is a delegate method that gets called immediately:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status;
```

I'm wondering if a similar method exists for accepting or rejecting Push Notifications.  I'm aware of how to prompt, as well as how to test for status, but not how to do something immediately after a user accepts or rejects the notification.

I would like to prompt the user for Push Notification, and based on their response do a certain action, such as redirect the ViewController one way or another.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a great deal of research on this and - unfortunately - the status of that accept/decline option appears to be entirely opaque.

You can determine that the user doesn't have push notifications enabled (using UIApplication's `isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications`), but not *why* it isn't enabled (ie. determine whether it's a "never prompted" or "prompted and then declined or later disabled" state).

I strongly suspect that this was a conscious design decision by Apple to make it more difficult for developers to hound users who've opted out. There are legitimate reasons to have this information, though, so I hope in the future they reconsider.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that but you can check that every time the app gets into foreground. This would solve your case when you can take action at the moment the user opens the app.

If you want to do that on background (in case you want to report your server that user has been disabled notification for example) you can always run some background task (like "Background fetch") to check the status.